# SQL: calculate the sum of each column and convert them into rows

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

My current table includes more than 100 columns and I need to calculate the sum of each column and convert them into rows. Since there are more than 100 column, it is not convenient to use the unpivote clause. Is there any other way to do that?
Below is a snapshot of the original table:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 23 | 44 |
| 33 | 45 |

and here is what i need:

| variable | sum_variable |
| --- | --- |
| col1 | 56 |
| col2 | 89 |

Can you help me with this please?

Comment: The short answer is no, there is no ***convenient*** way.  The need/desire to do this often points to a need to 'fix' the ***initial*** data structure.  That said, BigQuery is deliberately a columnar database.  That brings numerous advantages, along with an expectation that you'll be working to specific patterns.  So, one relevant question becomes; why are you trying to avoid the columnar pattern that bigquery expects?  Might that indicate that you're using the wrong database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below

```
select split(kv, ':')[offset(0)] as variable, 
  sum(cast(split(kv, ':')[offset(1)] as int64)) as sum_variable
from data t, unnest(split(translate(to_json_string(t), '{}"', ''))) kv
group by variable
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: LOL, encode as json then unnest it, clever.

Comment: yes, and I agree - in this case using unpivot is not too practical, so I deleted my initial answer

Comment: Now, do that after the OP puts `{`, `}`, `"` in the column names ;)

Comment: `Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 300 characters long.`

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant thanks so much! It worked!! If you don't mind, I wanted to ask another question. Now instead of taking the sum, I'd like to see if I can calculate the correlations among input and output variables. I have written the query as```(Avg(y * x) - (Avg(x) * Avg(y))) / (stddev(x) * stddev(y)) AS pearson```. Do you know I can replace the variance clause with what I have written?

Comment: sure, no problem. please post new question with relevant new details and we will be happy to further help you. :o)