# SQL: calculate the sum of each column and return them as rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to calculate the sum of each column and return them as rows. What I need is very similar to this question: [SQL: calculate the sum of each column and convert them into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69165243/sql-calculate-the-sum-of-each-column-and-convert-them-into-rows)
and the answer provided works very well, until I don't have any null values in my column. (I get "bad null value error") Could anyone help how the provided query can be modified in handling null values?

Answer (score 2):

Use below - as you can see you can use `safe_cast` instead of `cast` here

```
select split(kv, ':')[offset(0)] as variable, 
  sum(safe_cast(split(kv, ':')[offset(1)] as int64)) as sum_variable
from your_table t, unnest(split(translate(to_json_string(t), '{}"', ''))) kv
group by variable
```

so, if apply to dummy data as

[image]

output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IF` expression to default to 0 instead of `null`:

```
IF(yourfield, 0, yourfield)
```

Another way is to use `IFNULL`:

```
IFNULL(yourfield, 0)
```

These ways provide a way to default some values instead of `null` if `null` is unacceptable for a scenario.

EDIT:

As Andrew pointed out (thanks!), `COALESCE` is another option:

```
COALESCE(yourfield,0)
```

Comment: Or `coalesce(<column>,0)` for a more generic ansi compliant option.

Comment: @Andrew you are making a great point! Thank you. I have edited my answer accordingly.